# How to set insets

Tags: java, vaadin, insets

How can I set the insets to a Vaadin label.I have below developed.I want to have some space between the button and label.

```
        button_3 = new Button();
        button_3.setCaption("Button");
        button_3.setImmediate(true);
        button_3.setWidth("-1px");
        button_3.setHeight("-1px");
        horizontalLayout_4.addComponent(button_3);

        // prize_set_label
        prize_set_label = new Label();
        prize_set_label.setImmediate(false);
        prize_set_label.setWidth("-1px");
        prize_set_label.setHeight("-1px");
        prize_set_label.setValue("small:23");
        horizontalLayout_4.addComponent(prize_set_label);
```

Comment: Are you developing the UI by hand? ...I recommend you give something like Netbeans a try to save yourself the time and effort.  Spacing like you want above can be easily done.  Even if you still want to do it manually, the code generation with Netbeans UI is tidy enough so that you an see how to do it yourself.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk no this  is a vaadin ui.I have used tools like window builder but in vaadin it does not provide similar support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add spacing between components in (most) layouts, you can use setSpacing(boolean) - e.g. `horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(true);`

If you want to change the *size* of the spacing, you must change this in CSS.

I don't understand what you are doing there with the size of the button & label; as far as I'm aware, setting the width/height to negative values is not valid in Vaadin.

Comment: Thanks Charles.It works as you said I can not set the insets by it but it gives me enough space though.Setting -1px means it handles width and height by auto.It takes the available space in the layout I guess.

Comment: Ahh - Of course! Normally, you'd use `setSizeUndefined()` to be clearer. [This chapter](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.settings.html) in the Book Of Vaadin explains how to change the size of the spacing/margins.

Answer (score 0):

To some who want to modify a Component `Insets` (e.g. for a clean, readable `CellEditor` under some LaF (yes I'm looking at you Nimbus!)), the insets are actually the one from the Component `Border`, so you need to specify an [empty border](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder--) or just remove with it `Component.setBorder(null)`.

N.B. that if no border is defined, it's the Component [peer](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week6/09.html) insets that are used.